# Chances a skydiver has a seizure on the plane

Tags: statistics

Actual situation.  Between 3/17/2019 and 7/17/2022, a skydiver had 3 seizures.  His last seizure was on the 20-minute plane ride to jump.  He made 394 of these 20-minute plane rides in the stated time period.  What are the odds (1 in #) he would have a seizure on a 20-minute plane ride to altitude? Because it happened.  I've calculated 87,696 "20-minute time segments," 394 of these segments were on a plane, and of the 3 seizures, 1 was on a plane ride.  The odds of him having a seizure on a plane ride are 1 in what number?  Thanks!

Comment: What is the significance of the 87,696 twenty-minute time segments?

Comment: It may not be.  It's the length of the plane ride to altitude to jump.  I figure having made (almost) 394 jumps, that's 394 out of 87,696 segments 1 of the 3 seizures could have occurred (and the 3rd did). 
 Thank you!

Comment: If he had one, then the probability he had one was $1$.  What the probability he would have had one is a different question and depends on whether seizures are affected by the environment (does he have seizures when asleep? is stress a trigger?)

Comment: Henry, that's my question - what is the probability he "would have had" one during a plane ride, based solely on time (nothing to do with triggers).  You can use his occasional 20-minute nap after lunch if you want.  We're talking about time only.  1,753,920 minutes between 3/17/2019 and 7/17/2022; 394 plane rides, each lasting 20 minutes.  3 occurrences.  What's the probability of one of these occurrences happening on one of the 394 plane rides lasting 20 minutes?  Thanks for your help!